# Empty Response In BSF Post Processor

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to use the BSF Post Processor with an HTTP request sampler. The body of the response is JSON, however it appears that I'm not seeing the body in my script.

Test script below:

```
var response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();

if (response.length > 0) {
    vars.put('foo', 'success');
}
else {
    vars.put('foo', 'failure');
}
```

Subsequent calls to the server are showing `'failure'` as the value of `foo`.

Attaching the debug post processor indicates that there is a response body:

```
{"success":true,"total":0,"results":[]}
```

Is it possible there's some setup I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) `vars.put()` method needs 2 strings

- Variable Name
- Variable Value

If you need to store long value into JMeter Variables you need to use [vars.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method instead.

Another option is to convert your  `13808513700` into string by surrounding it with quotation marks

```
vars.put('foo', '13808513700');
```

To learn more about predefined variables like *vars, props, ctx*, etc.check out [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

---

**UPDATE**

As original question have been modified, here is the modified answer.

You need to explicitly cast response to JavaScript String object as:

```
var response = new String(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
```

Comment: I tried to make the original question clearer. It's not a problem with the vars.put call, but which branch of the conditional is being taken.